# Updating External Database from Button Click (HTML, JavaScript, PHP, Ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've been working on a project for a while and this is the last item on my list. I need to update an external database after a button is clicked. I've tried many different things and browsed this website in particular for about 12 hours now. I still can't figure it out. Ajax is very foreign to me.

I'm hoping that someone here has some free time to point me in the right direction...

Here is a basic rundown of what I am trying to accomplish:

1. I create several buttons, each with unique ID's so I can isolate them in JavaScript.

   ```
   <?php 
   $n = 0;

   for ($z = 0; $z < $name_size; $z++) { ?>

       <tr class="number-rows">
           <td width="20%"><?php echo str_replace("_", " ", ucwords($name_array[$z], "_"));?></td>
           <td width="10%"><input type="number" id="new-number-<?php echo $number_array[$n]; ?>" class="number-update" value="" min="1" max="999999999" /></td>
           <td><a href = "javascript:void(0)" class = "send-update" onclick = "updateNumber(event, '<?php echo $number_array[$n]; ?>')">Update</a></td>
           <td width="15%" class="update-success" style="display:none"><span style="color:green">Successfully Updated!</span></td>
           <td width="15%" class="update-failure" style="display:none"><span style="color:red">Not Updated!</span></td>
           <?php $n = $n + 4;?>
       </tr>

   <?php
   }?>

   </tbody>
   ```
2. The input type="number" holds a new value entered by the user. There is a button right next to it, labelled "Update" (the next td element).
3. When "Update" is clicked, I need to pass the value of the input number field and the ID of the particular Update button that was clicked. I can do this with JavaScript fairly easily:

   function updateNumber(event, id) {

   ```
   //The id parameter is actually the row # from the database table I need to update. 
   //From this id, I generate unique td id's so I can isolate them in JavaScript. 

   var userInput = "new-number-" + id;
   var newNumber = document.getElementById(userInput);
   var updateNumber = newNumber.value;

   //The td with the unique id attached to it will contain the new number value I need to update my database with.
   //So now I have two variables of use, the id of the database table row, and the new number to update it with.
   //Next I need to either call a PHP function, or a PHP file so that I can connect to the database and insert the value.

   //Use AJAX here to call my PHP file? How do I pass
   ```

   }
4. Here is where I need to bridge the gap... How do I take those two variables, pass them to a PHP file, and have that file process the update to the database? I've been reading about AJAX, but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried to appending POST data (such as ?id=$X, value=$y, etc), but it seems to refresh the page with a URL containing that information. I'd like to keep the URL constant and have the information updated without a page reload if possible (in the true spirit of AJAX, as far as I understand).

Here is my PHP file that I need to work on as well to make it compatible with AJAX:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['value']) {

        //I use an SSL connection with login details elsewhere
        require_once('/path/to/connection.php');

        if (!$link) {
            echo "<br>This tool is not available at this time. Please try again later.";
        } //Can't connect to database

        else {

            $number_update = "UPDATE numbers SET price='".$_POST['value']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']"'";
            $send_update = $instance->query($number_update);

            if (!$send_update) {
                echo "There was an error while updating this listing.";
            }
            else {
                echo "Number updated succesfully.";
            }

            $instance->close();

        }

    }

?>
```

Thank you for your time all. I really look forward to hearing input from those who take some time to help me.

Comment: MySQL is deprecated and throwing raw `$_POST[]` into a query puts the script at risk of SQL injections. I recommend you change from `mysql` to `mysqli` Also where is your ajax that you have tried? Can't help you understand the problem with your ajax source code without seeing it....

Comment: my connection.php file uses mysqli